# Ubuntu 18.04 apt install keystone fails because of dependency errors "this may mean that you have requested an impossible situation

Tags: apt, server, 18.04, package-management

I have this problem with keystone installation.

[image: dependencies are not going to be installed]

Content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main
deb [arch=ppc64el,arm64,amd64] 
http://mirror.hosting90.cz/mariadb/repo/10.3/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src [arch=ppc64el,arm64,amd64] http://mirror.hosting90.cz/mariadb/repo/10.3/ubuntu bionic main
```

Content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudarchive-rocky.list`

```
deb http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/rocky main
# deb-src http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/rocky main
# deb-src http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/rocky main
```

Content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudarchive-rocky.list.save`

```
deb http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/rocky main
# deb-src http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/rocky main
```

Comment: "You have requested an impossible situation" usually means that you have made an unwise choice of sources to draw software packages from. Please edit your question to show us the complete list of your sources in /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d. Alternately, if you already suspect the mistake you made that caused this problem, don't hold back. The more you tell us, the better we can advise you.

Comment: Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to user535733 for advice! The solution was to comment out the first line in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudarchive-rocky.list`

```
# deb http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/rocky main
# deb-src http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/rocky main
# deb-src http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/rocky main
```

Comment: Glad you see you figured it out!